# SQL Server Poor Query performance on production db

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

The query below performs poorly on a production database but seems fine on a development database. All the tables involved are identical, same columns, datatype, indexes, etc. The production database has slightly more records (maybe +10%). In SSMS the query takes 25-30 seconds to return any results, <1 sec on the dev copy.

The query is generated by a web based crm application via php code. (SuiteCrm)
The production and dev database are on the same server. The dev copy was created by restoring a backup of the production db.
I do see differences between the two execution plans but I don't understand why they would differ if the tables are identical. (I don't have any experience with execution plans)

```
SELECT TOP (@topcount) *
FROM   (SELECT contacts.id,
               LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name, '') + N' '
                           + ISNULL(contacts.last_name, ''))) AS NAME,
               contacts.first_name,
               contacts.last_name,
               contacts.salutation,
               accounts.NAME                                  account_name,
               jtl0.account_id                                account_id,
               contacts.title,
               contacts.phone_work,
               jt1.user_name                                  assigned_user_name,
               jt1.created_by                                 assigned_user_name_owner,
               N'Users'                                       assigned_user_name_mod,
               contacts.date_entered,
               contacts.date_modified,
               contacts.assigned_user_id,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY contacts.date_modified ASC)       AS row_number
        FROM   contacts
               LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm
                      ON contacts.id = contacts_cstm.id_c
               LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts jtl0
                      ON contacts.id = jtl0.contact_id
                         AND jtl0.deleted = 0
               LEFT JOIN accounts accounts
                      ON accounts.id = jtl0.account_id
                         AND accounts.deleted = 0
                         AND accounts.deleted = 0
               LEFT JOIN users jt1
                      ON contacts.assigned_user_id = jt1.id
                         AND jt1.deleted = 0
                         AND jt1.deleted = 0
        WHERE  (( ( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' )
                   OR ( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.last_name, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                         OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.last_name, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' )
                   OR (( contacts.phone_mobile LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                          OR contacts.phone_work LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                          OR contacts.phone_other LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                          OR contacts.phone_fax LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                          OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.phone_mobile, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.phone_work, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.phone_other, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.phone_fax, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.assistant_phone, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                          OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.assistant_phone, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.phone_fax, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.phone_other, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.phone_work, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.phone_mobile, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' ))
                   OR ( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.assistant, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                         OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.assistant, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' )
                   OR ( contacts.id IN (SELECT bean_id
                                        FROM   (SELECT eabr.bean_id
                                                FROM   email_addr_bean_rel eabr
                                                       JOIN email_addresses ea
                                                         ON ( ea.id = eabr.email_address_id )
                                                WHERE  eabr.deleted = 0
                                                       AND ea.email_address LIKE N'abe krebs%') email_derived) )
                   OR ( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(accounts.NAME, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                         OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(accounts.NAME, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' )
                   OR (( contacts.first_name LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                          OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.last_name, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%'
                          OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.last_name, '') + N' '
                                         + ISNULL(contacts.first_name, ''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' )) ))
               AND contacts.deleted = 0) AS a
WHERE  row_number > 0
```

I've noticed that the query performance is fine if I remove

```
SELECT TOP (@topcount) * FROM
```

or remove

```
( contacts.id IN 
    (select bean_id  
        from (SELECT eabr.bean_id ...
```

or remove

```
        OR ( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(accounts.name,''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' 
    OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(accounts.name,''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' )
```

Something else that concerns  me is if I try to run the database tuning advisor on the production db the DTA crashes every time, even if I select one small table.
There is a maintenance plan with Reorganize Index that runs nightly.
I checked everything I can think of and can't find any differences between the two databases.
What could be causing the poor performance and why only on the one database?

Comment: That query is pretty horrible. Using things like `LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name, ''))` means that the condition is unsargable and why does it repeat the same conditions multiple times?

Comment: You are also using TOP but there is no ORDER BY so you have no way of knowing which rows will get returned.

Comment: Making "accounts.name" NOT NULL and ensuring the data never gets entered as null (add a "default ('')" to it) would allow you to eliminate some of that redundant code.  And any time you use TOP you MUST have an "ORDER BY" or your results are potentially non-deterministic.  But yeah, there's a lot of performance issues with this query...

Answer (score 1):

First that code is horrendous. This is a prime example of why you should not generate sql code. If you really need all those LTRIM, RTRIM functions for instance, then your database design needs work too. And you have the same OR condition in there multiple times.

```
(((LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name,''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' 
    OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name,''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' ) 
    OR ( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.last_name,''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' 
    OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.last_name,''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' )
```

Plus what is going on with your database design if this is even something you want to check:

```
  OR ( ( contacts.phone_mobile like N'abe krebs%' 
    OR contacts.phone_work like N'abe krebs%' 
    OR contacts.phone_other like N'abe krebs%' 
    OR contacts.phone_fax like N'abe krebs%'
```

Or

```
OR ( contacts.id IN 
        (select bean_id  
            from (SELECT eabr.bean_id 
            FROM email_addr_bean_rel eabr JOIN email_addresses ea ON (ea.id = eabr.email_address_id) 
            WHERE eabr.deleted=0 AND ea.email_address LIKE N'abe krebs%') email_derived))
```

After all very few email addresses have spaces in them.

OR conditions generally slow down performance and by adding a bunch of them that will never affect the result you are creating performance problems.

if you are passing in the full name of this person why are you using like?

If you have both a first and last name field what is the liklihood that this name even exists properly inthat field? I can't even be sure you are getting the correct results, but I woudl find it highly unlikely.

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name,''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%' ) 
    OR ( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.last_name,''))) LIKE N'abe krebs%'
```

this makes more sense to me

```
where contacts.first_name = N'abe'
and contacts.last_name= N'krebs'
```

On the other hand if you are stuck with this code for reasons beyond your control, I would suspect that the difference between prod and dev comes down to two things. First statistics may be out of date (this is different from indexing).

Second, some people develop on dev databases that are considerably smaller than the prod ones. That is always a bad idea. Code that runs fine on a small dataset is often poorly performing on a large one.

Comment: I agree this is an ugly query. It is comes from a global search function of the crm app. So I suppose it is trying to acount for the fact that a user mahe have enter a phone number, email, fax, etc, etc.

Comment: There are better ways to do a gloabal search. Ones that won't kill performance on your system.  Of coudsre this sounds like some sort of COTS (commerical off-the shelf) product and I have never yet seen one of those that queried the database correctly and I have had to support a lot of those applications through the years. Since you are stuck with it, I'd suggest that updating statistics is your best bet.

Comment: It is an open source CRM app called Suite. It was selected by the sales dept without consulting me. It was installed by an IT guy who has since left the company. I will try to update statistics and see what happens. Still wondering why the DTA crashes???

Comment: I think the global search is stupid but users have seen the performance difference and are saying there must be something wrong with the database.

Comment: Updated statistics using sp_updatestats No change. Still don't understand why the query performs better on another database that is a copy of the production db. Could there be some sort of corruption?

Comment: Could be a  hardware issue.  Also is the other server the same operating system and pathced to the same level as far as teh database and OS? Sometimes a small difference in environment can cause problems.

Comment: The 2 databases are on the same server, same drive. The dev db was created by restoring a backup of the production db. There is a maintenance plan running nightly on the production db that does Integrity Check, Reorg Indexes, and Backup. I also created a cleaner version of the query; no Rtrim, Ltrim, IsNull, removed stuff from the where clause -- same performance. If I remove the "accounts.name LIKE N'abe krebs%'", then it works great. The accounts table has exactly the same number of records in the two dbs.

Comment: I'm will tell the users that the application creates crap sql queries but they still will ask, "why is it better with the other database?"